# Kubernetes PersistentVolumClaim is not bound - OpenVpn Helm Chart

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-helm

I have a single Kubernetes node running an a VmWare vm. I am trying to launch an [openvpn Helm Chart](https://kubeapps.com/charts/stable/openvpn).  When I run the install command, I get output, but then both the pod and PersistentVolumeClaim get stuck in "Pending" state.  What am I missing?

**VM Host**: Centos 7

**K8**: 1.8.1

**Install Command:**

```
helm install stable/openvpn --version 2.0.0
```

**Volume Claim**

```
PersistentVoluemClaim is not bound: "Claim name"
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to persist your configuration which helps you overcome from restarting pod or machine you should create PV. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

The linked chart created PVC by itself.

https://github.com/jfelten/helm-charts/blob/master/charts/openvpn/templates/certs-pvc.yaml

If you don't need to persist data inside the pod you can disable persistence  option from `values.yaml` 
https://github.com/jfelten/helm-charts/blob/684ee0dd26e4c294613b44577e51603fc3a4e5c6/charts/openvpn/values.yaml#L22

```
Enabled: false
```